# EVITAR EXCEPCIÓN ERROR 404 API REST C#

Tags: c#, api

Tengo una funcion que consulta a traves una api rest una fecha, que puede o no existir.

```
internal static DateTime? getLastUpdate(string nameSensor)
    {
        DateTime dateResult = new DateTime();
        try
        {
            var url = $"https://xxx/data/api/getLastUpdate/"+ nameSensor;
            LoggFile.WriteToFile("url: "+ url);
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.ContentType = "aplication/json";
            request.Accept = "aplication/json";
            

            using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (Stream strReader = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    if (strReader == null) return null;
                    using (StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(strReader))
                    {
                        string responseBody = objReader.ReadToEnd();
                        if (DateTime.TryParse(responseBody, out dateResult))
                        {
                            LoggFile.WriteToFile(DateTime.Now + "-- update-safenet: " + responseBody);
                            return dateResult;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return null;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LoggFile.WriteToFile(DateTime.Now + "-- UPDATE (ERROR) : " + ex.ToString());
            return dateResult;
        }
    }
```

Utilice el tipo de dato DateTime? porque es posible que obtenga una respuesta nula, pero no he podido cachear el response y consultar su status y en caso de ser 404 u otro tipo de error retornar null en la función y que no reviente el programa, intente hacerlo desde el catch pero igual el programa se detiene, de que forma puedo tomar la respuesta aun siendo 404?

Answer (score 0):

De esta forma podras obtener el status code del response y poder hacer alguna validacion con eso

```
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    if((int)response.StatusCode == 404)
    {
        //hacer acciones necesarias
    }
...
}
```

Referencia
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330856/getting-http-status-code-number-200-301-404-etc-from-httpwebrequest-and-ht